# inserting id to postgresql query using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

```html
var Integer = require('integer');

client.query('INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, email, password, phone_number) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)', [Integer(), req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.username, pwd, req.body.phoneNumber]
```

This is my function where I trying to post id to my postgreqsl table.
I installed integer for node by npm, set integer data type for my id column in pg and it does not work when i was trying to put it into the database.

I had a such error:

> { error: invalid input syntax for integer: "{"high":0,"low":0}"

When I imported uuivdv4 to the file and changed the Integer() by uuidv4(),(of course i remember about changing data type in id column) i had a good insert.

```html
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

client.query('INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, email, password, phone_number) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)', [uuidv4(), req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.username, pwd, req.body.phoneNumber]
```

Comment: Please clarify your question and what is your intended behavior. The `integer` lib is an external package that wraps around native `Number` in JS, and returns an `Object` - so that is why you get an `invalid input syntax for integer` error.

Comment: You can just use omit the `id` from your query. I mean if that is PK traditionally it has a auto_increment property sate or timestamp property set. So leave the `id` and let the db do it's thing. addtionally, you can also insert null in place of Integer() which will do the same thing

Comment: The only thing i want is just to make id auto-increment to my user tabel.The id can't be null because i set a not null property in the database.

Answer (score 0):

`integer` package is not intended to generate a random integer number like that of `uuid/v4`, which generates a random UUID string. The integer is meant for converting a string literal to number e.g. `'123'` to `123`.

The below will work for you.

Updated code:

```js
let randNumber= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000);
client.query('INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, email, password, phone_number) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)', [randNumber, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.username, pwd, req.body.phoneNumber]
```

EDIT :
Change the column `Id` in your users to `auto-increment` and use the below query to insert.

```js
client.query('INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password, phone_number) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)', [req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.username, pwd, req.body.phoneNumber]
```

After you have changed it to `autoincrement`, no need to specify the `id` for inserting.

Comment: Thank for your answer but how i can add simple id to each insert(not random)?

Comment: you can set the db colum 'id' as auto increment so that it will automatically generate the id. No need to insert explicitly

Comment: Thanks, I changed integer data type of my id column on serial which is auto_incremented in postgresql and it works!